# react material-ui breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

const RightComponent=styled(Box)(({theme})=>({
width:'17%',
background:'#ffffff',
padding:5,
marginTop:10,
marginLeft:10,
textAlign:'center',
[theme.breakpoints.down('md')]:{
display:'none'
}
}));

//Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'down')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'down')

this occurs at runtime ans plzz

Comment: maybe its because you forget root:{} see this link=>https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/#theme-breakpoints-down-key-media-query

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this issue using the code that you provided.  Try reproducing in a CodeSandbox and update your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.